# Visual Studio 17 Local IIS generated random KEYS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I didn't ask any question in a long time to here. Recently I focused ASP.NET oldest projects

I'm weak related with IIS express configurations Actually I'm not sure solve my Issue  with  IIS express configurations. Alright, When I started debugging in My ASP.NET project My IIS generate a new key my debug URL.

Like This :

http://localhost:26266/(S(**bhn3b0taphw4jp3mezoyeasn**))/Default.aspx

http://localhost:26266/(S(**kqjpq0iinptyk54oevuqgudi**))/Default.aspx

How can I disable it on my VisualStudio.

If I ask you stupid question. Please let me know.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What you observed is the so called cookie-less sessions, https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/using-cookie-less-session-in-Asp-Net/ To disable it, modify your ASP.NET settings, not IIS Express.

Comment: on `web.config` this section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection?view=netframework-4.8 check the `cookieless` attribute

Comment: Why do you need to disable?  It is better to explain your issues, not what you think may solve issue.